# Disable <a> tag in Angular conditionally

Tags: html, angular, angular9

I'm trying to disable a link in an Angular template. May be asking an impossible question. Is it possible to do something like this?

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/details', item.id]" [disable]="disable">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
        <h4>text text text</h4>  
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

When the link is disabled I want it to behave `<a>` tag is just as a regular `<div>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code. Change `href` value based on the condition and apply some styles

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wd8sa5?file=src/app/app.component.scss)

**Template**

```
<a [routerLink]="disable ? null : ['/details', 1]" [ngClass]="{'anchor-disable' : disable}">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h4>text text text</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a.anchor-disable {
  color: black;
  cursor: text;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to give you an idea.

Can we do something like this?

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h4>text text text</h4>  
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
<a [routerLink]="['/details', item.id]">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h4>text text text</h4>  
      </div>
    </div>
</a>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I could, but the whole reason I want to do this is that the contents of the a tag is pretty complex. So I would be rewriting the same code twice. I guess I could separate that out to a different component.. But I was hoping for a simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

If the content of your a-tag is that complex, then just outsource it in its own component or into ng-template, so you can put it into the a-tag and the div without it being a huge mess. I don't think conditionally replacing the a-tag with a div as you would like to do is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular material, you can use mat-button property and ngClass to achieve this

```
<a mat-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" disabled="{{isDisabled}}"
    [ngClass]="{'simple-text': isDisabled}">
    Sample link
</a>
```

css

```
.simple-text {
  color: black !important;
}
```

stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkmkn9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="disable ? null : ['/details', item.id]" [class.disabled]="disable">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
        <h4>text text text</h4>  
        </div>
    </div>
</a>

.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```